# Find sum of $1 + \cos \theta + \frac{1}{2!}\cos 2\theta + \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Find the sum of following series:

$$1 + \cos \theta + \frac{1}{2!}\cos 2\theta + \cdots$$

where $\theta \in \mathbb R$.

My attempt: I need hint to start.

Comment: Hint: $\cos(n\theta) = \Re( e^{i n\theta})$ for $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:
$$
1+\cos x + \frac{1}{2!}\cos 2x + \ldots = \Re(e^{0ix} + e^{1ix} + \frac{1}{2!}e^{2ix} + \ldots)=\Re e^{e^{ix}}
$$

$$
e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x\\\Longrightarrow e^{e^{ix}} = e^{\cos x}e^{i\sin x}=e^{\cos x}(\cos(\sin x)+i\sin(\sin x))
$$
Your sum is
$$
e^{\cos x}\cos(\sin x)
$$

Comment: Spoilers with \$\$ doesn't work properly

Answer (score 3):

Hint to start
$$
1+\cos \theta + \frac{1}{2!}\cos(2\theta)+\cdots = \mathcal{Re}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\mathrm{e}^{ik\theta}}{k!} = \mathcal{Re}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\left(\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}\right)^k}{k!}
$$
Also remember that in the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}=\mathrm{e}^x
$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINTS**: You have $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\cos(k\theta)}{k!}$$

Remember that:
$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
And:
$$\cos(\theta)=\Re{e^{i\theta}}$$

Comment: Is $\cos\theta$ really equal to $e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: Then what is $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal typo fixed